# Sampling rate analog to digital converter

Tags: adc, sampling

I am a novice in microcontroller subject and have just learned that ADC converts analogue voltage on a pin of, for example, an Arduino, to a binary number. Since the ADC on the Arduino is a 10 bit ADC, we will have 2<sup>10</sup> discrete analogue levels. Does it mean that the number of samples during the acquisition time is 2<sup>10</sup> and the intervals between these samples gives the sampling time?

Edit:So here in the picture with two bits we have 4 levels. When I look at this graph I see the signal has been sampled 4 times equal to 2<sup>2</sup>.

[image]

Comment: No, it means that each sample is converted to an integer value between 0 and 1023 \$(0\rightarrow 2^{10}-1)\$

Comment: Well wouldn't that make the number of samples 1024?

Comment: No, it means that each voltage sample is converted to a binary number between 00 0000 0000 and 11 1111 1111

Comment: One ADC reading is one sample, as far as the user is concerned.

Comment: Could you please take a look at the edit I made to my question.

Comment: @Chu So the whole graph here is one sample?

Comment: The signal is sampled in time and quantized in voltage.  For a 10 bit ADC, you get 1024 quantization levels per sample.

Comment: @alex so sampling in time has no relation to quantization of voltage?

Comment: Yes.  It is possible to sample without quantizing (i.e. sample and hold) or quantize without sampling (i.e. comparator).

Comment: Also, that graph you posted I would describe as showing continuous time (no samples) with four quantization levels.

Comment: Ok thank you. I am still a bit confused about the applications. I thought we do sampling so that the computer could process the analogue signal. So when do we sampling and when quantization?

Comment: @alex I just did some googling. Apparently we do quantization on the sampled signal to round them up and sampling is done before the quantization. But from this I would conclude that the number of samples is equal to the number of quantized numbers.Would that make the answer to my above question YES?(in case we do quantization after sampling?)

Comment: Specifically which question?

Comment: Each time you sample, you get one level.  That level is then quantized into some number of quantization levels, and the result is an integer that represents the quantized level of that sample.  You get one number per sample, but that number has 1024 possible values when you use a 10-bit quantizer.

Comment: The question that I have asked in this forum, with the title Sampling rate analog to digital converter

Comment: See edits.  I added a couple of pictures that will perhaps make things more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, during the acquisition time the converter connects a sampling capacitor in what is called a sample and hold circuit to the pin and charges it up.  At the end of the sampling time, the capacitor is disconnected and the charge stored is measured.  I believe the Atmega microcontrollers use successive approximation, which require one ADC clock cycle per bit (so 10 clock cycles for 10 bits).  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog-to-digital_converter and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successive_Approximation_ADC for more details on how they work.

Note that the ADC input is actually a switched capacitor input; this can present several design challenges as the capacitor has to be able to charge completely while also not affecting the circuit that it is connected to.  Some solutions involve adding a buffer amplifier or a low-pass filter or even being very careful with the scan order so that a known voltage is sampled before each measurement so any history effects are minimized.

Edit: Here is a decent graph representing sampling and quantization.  The blue curve is the input analog waveform, the black dots are the samples, and the red curve is the quantized output.  The result is one n-bit number per sample.

[image: quantization]

This is a snip from the atmega datasheet showing the ADC conversion timing.  The sampling time is the first clock cycle and a half where the sample and hold capacitor is connected.  The term 'acquisition time' is synonymous with sampling time for SAR ADCs.  Once the capacitor is disconnected, the successive approximation ADC converts that sampled voltage into a binary number over the next 10 clock cycles.  At the end of this time, the converted 10-bit number appears in the ADCH/ADCL registers.  Each sample produces one number, though this number has 10 bits and as such 1024 possible values.  The ADC can sample the input voltage and convert it once every 14 ADC clock cycles.

[image: atmega adc]

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the internal workings of the ADC, it may take a number of samples in the process of generating one reading that is presented to the user (or calling program).

Generally when a programmer talks of averaging several ADC samples, he will be referring to the completed reading that the ADC provides, not to any sampling that is part of the internal working of the ADC.